# I have a task to decrease the spatial resolution of an image but the canvas size must stay constant for the new image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

The spatial resolution is decreased by using the imresize function e.g. 4x4 image is converted to 2x2 image but the canvas size also decreases due to dimensions.

Is there any way to manipulate the size of the pixels to get the same canvas size?

Answer (score 2):

Resolution is very often misunderstood to mean number of pixels or size of a pixel. In fact, the size of a pixel gives the maximum possible resolution of an image, but lower resolution is possible.

Resolution is the ability to distinguish small details. The smallest distance between two small dots that can still be distinguished (resolved) is [the resolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_resolution). The resolution of a digital image is given by the density of pixels (or pixel size) as well as the optical system that created the image.

For a good imaging system, the optics and the image sensor are matched, such that the sampling of the sensor does not reduce the resolution of the image (which would introduce aliasing), but also doesn’t oversample the image (in which case we’d have more pixels than information).

One simple way of reducing the resolution of an image without changing the number of pixels is to simulate the effect of an optical system with lower resolution. Any low-pass filtering will do, but Gaussian filtering will yield the best results.

Answer (score 1):

*As Chris' answer suggested a lowpass filter is the way to go to simulate a lower resolution optical system. Please read through that question and decide appropriately the method that suits your application requirements*

---

### Pseudo-Resolution Adjustment (decrease/downscale)

**Quick and Dirty Solution:**

To increase the scaled-down image back to the original size the `repelem()` function can be used to repeat the elements. In this example using a `Resolution_Factor = 0.5` will decrease the fidelity of the image by a factor of 2. On the left of the figure below is the original 4-by-4 image and on the right is the 4-by-4 image that is *Pseudo-Resolution Adjusted*. The image on the right appears to be lower quality but the spatial dimensions remain the same. Please keep in mind the `Resolution_Factor` for this script should be equal to or lower than `1` (decrease). ***Keep in mind that the terminology I used here is quite vague and not considered concrete in anyway.***

[image: Pseudo-Resolution Adjustment Black and White Images]

```
Resolution_Factor = 0.5;

Image = [0   10  20  30;
         40  50  60  70;
         80  90  100 110;
         120 140 150 160];

[Image_Height,Image_Width,~] = size(Image);

Resized_Image = imresize(Image,[round(Image_Height*Resolution_Factor) round(Image_Width*Resolution_Factor)]);
Resolution_Adjusted_Image = repelem(Resized_Image,round(1/Resolution_Factor),round(1/Resolution_Factor));

Image = uint8(Image);                  
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);
title("Original Image");

subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Resolution_Adjusted_Image);
title(["Pseudo-Resolution Adjusted Image";"(kept pixel quality)"]);

fprintf("The size of the orginal image is:");
disp(size(Image));

fprintf("The size of the psuedo-resolution adjusted image is:");
disp(size(Resolution_Adjusted_Image));
```

---

[image: Pseudo-Resolution Adjustment Colour Images]

```
Resolution_Factor = 0.25;
     
Image = imread("peppers.png");
     
Image = uint8(Image);                  
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);
title("Original Image");

[Image_Height,Image_Width,~] = size(Image);

Resized_Image = imresize(Image,[round(Image_Height*Resolution_Factor) round(Image_Width*Resolution_Factor)]);
Resolution_Adjusted_Image = repelem(Resized_Image,round(1/Resolution_Factor),round(1/Resolution_Factor));

subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Resolution_Adjusted_Image);
title(["Pseudo-Resolution Adjusted Image";"(kept pixel quality)"]);

fprintf("The size of the orginal image is:");
disp(size(Image));

fprintf("The size of the psuedo-resolution adjusted image is:");
disp(size(Resolution_Adjusted_Image));
```